# Increment by on substring -SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of strings like so:

```
M308_7
M308_8
M308_9
M308_10
```

and want to grab the MAX number from the last digits after the "_" of the string and increment this number by one (so the number it should return is 11)
I read on other posts to convert the last digits to integers as 9 is higher than 10 in alphabetical and that was the reason for it returning _9 as the MAX.
I have done this but still the value being returned is 9 when it should be 10

See below what I have so far..

```
                select 
                @BomNo = MAX(case when CHARINDEX('_',HeaderNo.No_)>0 then 
                CAST(SUBSTRING(HeaderNo.No_, 6, len(CHARINDEX('_',HeaderNo.No_))) AS INT)else 0 end)
                --MAX(case when CHARINDEX('_',NavBomHeader.No_)>0 then CAST(SUBSTRING(HeaderNo.No_,CHARINDEX('_',HeaderNo.No_)+1,len(CHARINDEX('_',HeaderNo.No_))) AS INT) else 0 end)+1
                from nameoftable as HeaderNo
                where SUBSTRING(HeaderNo.No_, 1,  case when CHARINDEX('_',HeaderNo.No_)>0 then CHARINDEX('_',HeaderNo.No_)-1 else len(HeaderNo.No_) end) ='M308'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, No_ VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl (No_) VALUES
('M308_7'),
('M308_8'),
('M308_9'),
('M308_10');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT NextNo = MAX(TRY_CAST(RIGHT(No_, LEN(No_) - pos) AS INT)) + 1
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('_', No_)) AS t(pos);
```

**Output**

```
+--------+
| NextNo |
+--------+
|     11 |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a design flaw in your database.  I suspect that you should be using an identity column.

In any case, the answer to your question is logic like this:

```
select concat('M308_', max(try_convert(int, stuff(no_, 1, charindex('_', no_), ''))) + 1)
from (values ('M308_7'), ('M308_8'), ('M308_9'), ('M308_10')) v(no_);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9ed564ff04622c33ccf59d81812e0fe6) is a db<>fiddle.